# Kendo ComboBox - How to select option based on its text() rather than value()?

Tags: combobox, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, kendo-combobox

I am really struggling to select an option from my combo box based on the text rather than value. I have a combo box which has a datasource attached to it which are countries. These countries are stored in the database. I want the default country to be "United Kingdom".
At the moment I am doing the following:

```
combobox.select(combobox.text("United Kingdom"));
```

However, this only shows the text and doesn't actually select it because the select function does not trigger. Any help with this?? I want the value to be applied. I have an alert in the select function which is not appearing.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [select](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/combobox#methods-select) method of the widget and pass a predicate

```
combobox.select(function(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.text === "Apples"; //note that 'text' === dataTextField
});
```

Here is a runnable [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OBAm) demonstrating this approach.

Comment: I've tried that as well and it still doesn't work. It just display the right text rather than actually selecting it.

Comment: when I do what you said and try and alert the value via: alert(combobox.value()); it alerts the text rather than the actual value which is a number.

Comment: Updated the answer withe a runnable demo. Nevertheless, here it is:
http://dojo.telerik.com/OBAm

Comment: $("#combobox").kendoComboBox({
  dataSource: [
    { id: 1, name: "Apples" },
    { id: 2, name: "Oranges" }
  ],
  dataTextField: "name",
  dataValueField: "id",
  select:function(e){
    alert(999);
  }
}); i included the select function and the alert does not show on page load??

Comment: As it is explained in the docs, select event is triggered only on user interaction.
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/combobox#events-select

Answer (score 3):

Selecting kendo comboBox value explicitly from javascript don't trigger the "Select" event.

In order achieve that you have to trigger the "Select" event after setting the required value.
e.g.

```
 var myComboBox = $('#comboBoxId').data('kendoComboBox');
 myComboBox.text("United Kingdom");
 myComboBox.trigger("select");
```

Hope this will solve your purpose. Also check [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/observable#methods-trigger).